# consume third party webservice passing credentials

Tags: c#, web-services, networkcredentials

I am writing a console application to try to consume a third party webservice. This webservice has a password-type = PasswordText.

I am creating my credential like that:

```
Icredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
```

But i can't get the connection. If i have a test from soap UI i have a successful connection.

There is a form to set the password-type to Passwordtext in the NetworkCredential object??

Comment: Is that all? where is the rest of your code?

Comment: are you assigning the credentials to the proxy object??

Comment: no, i am not assigning the credential to the proxy but directly to the webservice like this:
`com.uri.RateBook rateBook = new com.uri.RateBook();System.Net.ICredentials credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
rateBook.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
rateBook.Credentials = credential;`

Comment: the "WSS-Password type" property of the webservice is set to "PasswordText"

Comment: perhaps this will help: rateBook.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Comment: Is this a service reference, or a web reference?

Comment: Solved how proposed in [this blog](http://blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx) capturing the request before sending it and setting the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set UseDefaultCredential to true.

"UseDefaultCredentials: Set this property to true when requests made by this WebRequest object should, if requested by the server, be authenticated using the credentials of the **currently logged on user**"

This also explains why it works from the Soap UI: you are logged in with valid credentials.

Comment: thx about the answers. 
i have tried setting UseDefaultCredential=false but it doesn't work anyway. I think that the problem is maybe because it pass the password like Base 64 string and i need to pass it explicitely PasswordText.